# How to create dynamical requests to backend depending on url angular 2

Tags: angular

I have an Angular app (it's production version). App is available at two links (http://blabla.com, http://test.com). Now: for whatever url you open the application, the front sends requests for backend by url (test.com/api), because it's hardcoded in environments.  And I should make requests to backend depending on what URL I have. For example, URL is blablabla.com and I have to create a request to backend blablabla/api

```
     private apiUrl = environment.apiUrl.replace(/[/]+$/, '');
    
     private getUrl(url: string): string 
        return `${this.apiUrl}/${url}`;
      }

     public get<TResponse extends ApiResponse<any>>(url: string, options?: ApiRequestOptions): Observable<any> {
    let requestUrl = this.getUrl(url);
    let httpOptions = this.getHttpOptions(options);
    if (options && options.observe) {
      return this.httpClient.get<TResponse>(requestUrl, {
        observe: options.observe,
        ...httpOptions,
      });
    } else {
      return this.httpClient.get<TResponse>(requestUrl, httpOptions);
    }
  }

    export const environment = {
      production: true,
      apiUrl: 'https://test.com/api/v1/',
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a service ex. getSomeDataService, you can inject your component and use there like this.
getSomeData.service.ts:

```js
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';
...
// headers if they are needed

getDataBack(url: string) {
        return this.http.get(url);
    }
```

somethig.component.ts:

```js
...
import {GetSomeDataService} from '../services/getSomeData.service';
...

// inject into constructor
constructor(private getSomeService: GetSomeDataService){}

// after that in ngOnInit or elsewhere

ngOnInit() {
   url = location.host+'/api'; // or location host
   this.getSomeService(url)
   .subscribe(response => console.log());
}
```

**Update**
So you have the following:

```js
// hardcoded url which located in src/environment.prod.ts not necessary
 //private apiUrl = environment.apiUrl.replace(/[/]+$/, '');
    
     private getUrl(url: string): string 
        //return `${this.apiUrl}/${url}`;
        //here change the logic..
          return `${location.host}/${url}`;
      }
```

Comment: url = location.host+'/api';

Comment: Could you show the part of the code: *Now: for whatever url you open the application, the front sends requests for backend by url (test.com/api), because it's hardcoded in environments.*

Answer (score 0):

You can only specify path and browser will append your current host (blablabla.com or the other). So, if your host is 'blablabla.com', method `makeRequest` will make request from 'blablabla.com/api'.

```
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  public makeRequest() {
    return this.http.get('/api');
  }
```

Comment: My answer is still relevant, because you do not need to specify url host if you want to get request from the domain your site is delivered from

Answer (score 0):

You can use `location.host` to get the current host name and then append your endpoint details.